# Content of second activity is not showing

Tags: android

So, content of second activity does not appear when app is running, although content is showing in xml design. Programming in Java on Android Studio. In similar article answer didn't help. I also tried just to put one element in second activity, same result. Thanks in advance!

This is code from `MainActivity.java`:

```
package todo.beginner.com.carchooser2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static todo.beginner.com.carchooser2.R.id.checkBoxPrice;
import static todo.beginner.com.carchooser2.R.id.checkBoxGas;
import static todo.beginner.com.carchooser2.R.id.checkBoxYear;
import static todo.beginner.com.carchooser2.R.id.checkBoxMileage;
import static todo.beginner.com.carchooser2.R.id.checkBoxCapacity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CheckBox check1, check2, check3, check4, check5;
    private static Button button_next;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerToCeckBox();
        OnClickButtonListener();
    }

    public void OnClickButtonListener() {
        button_next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button_next.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("todo.beginner.com.SecondActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }
        );


    }

    public void addListenerToCeckBox() {
        check1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(checkBoxCena);
        check1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Price is chosen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        check2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(checkBoxGads);
        check2.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Year is chosen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        check3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(checkBoxTilpums);
        check3.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Engine capacity is chosen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        check4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(checkBoxDegviela);
        check4.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Gas consumption is chosen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        check5 = (CheckBox)findViewById(checkBoxNobraukums);
        check5.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Mileage is chosen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

    }



}
```

This is from `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="todo.raitis.com.carchooser.MainActivity">

    <CheckBox
        android:text="Price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxPrice"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:text="Year"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxPrice"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkBoxPrice"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/checkBoxPrice"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxYear" />

    <CheckBox
        android:text="Engine Capacity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxCapacity"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxYear"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:text="Gas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxCapacity"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkBoxCapacity"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/checkBoxCapacity"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxGas" />

    <CheckBox
        android:text="Mileage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxGas"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkBoxGas"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/checkBoxGas"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxMileage" />

    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Choose criteria!"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is from `SecondActivity.java`:

```
package todo.beginner.com.carchooser2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }
}
```

And this is from activity_second.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TableRow
        android:background="#607D8B"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Car Name" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Price" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Year" />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Gas" />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Mileage" />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Capacity" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:background="#ECEFF1"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Audi" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5000" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2001" />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7" />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="280000" />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2.5" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Can you replace Intent intent = new Intent("todo.beginner.com.SecondActivity"); with Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the intent incorrectly. It should be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you're starting the activity correctly. Try changing `Intent intent = new Intent("todo.beginner.com.SecondActivity");` to `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);` in your MainActivity.